# Finding most active users using a specific tag with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a website where users can upload pictures and use tags in the description. I want to find out who are the most active users posting pictures using a specific tag in the last 10 days.

Here are the tables:

**cards** (posts)

```
+----+---------+---------+------------+
| id |  name   | user_id |    date    |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
|  1 | daw.jpg |       1 | 2020-01-25 |
|  2 | efs.jpg |       2 | 2020-01-25 |
|  3 | dwa.jpg |       1 | 2020-01-25 |
|  4 | wda.jpg |       3 | 2020-01-25 |
|  5 | efa.jpg |       2 | 2020-01-25 |
+----+---------+---------+------------+
```

**cards_tags**

```
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id | card_id | tag_id |      date_time      |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 | 2020-01-25 12:46:00 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 | 2020-01-24 13:26:00 |
|  3 |       1 |      3 | 2020-01-23 14:46:00 |
|  4 |       2 |      1 | 2020-01-22 15:51:00 |
|  5 |       2 |      3 | 2020-01-21 12:52:00 |
+----+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

**users**

```
+----+---------+-------+
| id |  name   | ect.. |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 | bush    |       |
|  2 | clinton |       |
|  3 | obama   |       |
|  4 | trump   |       |
|  5 | reagan  |       |
+----+---------+-------+
```

I got this SQL query working which gives me a list of the users using a specific tag in the last 10 days.

```
$q2 = $db->prepare('SELECT *
                    FROM cards_tags
                    JOIN cards ON cards_tags.card_id = cards.id
                    JOIN users ON cards.user_id = users.id
                    WHERE cards_tags.date_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
                    AND cards_tags.tag_id = :tag_id');
$q2->execute([':tag_id' => $tag->id()]);

while($data = $q2->fetch()) 
{
    echo $data['user'].' posts with the tag id : '.$tag->id().'<br>';
}
```

However, I want to know the occurrence of how many times the users have used the specific tag in the last 10 days and group them by users ID.

This is what I came up so far but its not working :

```
$q2 = $db->prepare('SELECT *, COUNT(users.id) AS occurrence
                    FROM cards_tags
                    JOIN cards ON cards_tags.card_id = cards.id
                    JOIN users ON cards.user_id = users.id
                    WHERE cards_tags.date_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
                    AND cards_tags.tag_id = :tag_id
                    GROUP BY users.id');
$q2->execute([':tag_id' => $tag->id()]);

while($data = $q2->fetch()) 
{
    echo $data['user'].' is trending with '.$data['occurrence'].' posts with the tag id : '.$tag->id().'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: I think you probably want `SELECT cards_tags.tag_id, COUNT(users.id) AS occurrence ... GROUP BY cards_tags.tag_id`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query, that might help you:

SELECT cards_tags.tag_id, COUNT(users.id) AS occurrence
                    FROM cards_tags
                    JOIN cards ON cards_tags.card_id = cards.id
                    JOIN users ON cards.user_id = users.id
                    WHERE cards_tags.date_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
                    AND cards_tags.tag_id = :tag_id
                    GROUP BY users.id');

Answer (score 0):

What does "not working" mean?  If you select only columns from `users`, then the query should be fine:

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) AS occurrence
FROM cards_tags ct JOIN
     cards c
     ON ct.card_id = c.id JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_id = u.id
WHERE ct.date_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND
     ct.tag_id = :tag_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY occurrence DESC;
```

I added an `ORDER BY` to be more consistent with your question.